# Ratio of Modified Bessel Function of First Kind with its derivative (of positive order)

Tags: limits, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the limit:
$lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x\frac{I_{\nu}'(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)}$ for real order $\nu > 0$.

Wolfram Alpha gives the result of $\nu$ for real order $\nu > 0$, but I can't see why. The recurrence relations regarding derivatives $2 I'_{\nu}(x) = I_{\nu-1}(x) + I_{\nu+1}(x)$ doesn't seem the right thing to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the series definition of the modified Bessel function of the first kind: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E2

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the alternative formula http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29.E2
$$I_{\nu}'(x)= I_{\nu+1}+\frac{\nu}{x}I_{\nu}(x)$$
and the asymptotic form for $I_{\nu}(x)\sim(\frac{x}{2})^{\nu}/\Gamma(\nu+1)\;$ for $x\rightarrow 0.$
Then you get 
$$x\frac{I_{\nu}'(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)}
=x\left(\frac{I_{\nu+1}(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)}  +  \frac{\nu}{x}\frac{I_{\nu}(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)}\right)
\sim\nu + x\frac{(\frac{x}{2})^{\nu+1}\Gamma(\nu+1)}{(\frac{x}{2})^{\nu}\Gamma(\nu+2)}\\
=\nu + x\frac{(\frac{x}{2})}{\nu+1}\\
$$
and therefore your limit is 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\frac{I_{\nu}'(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)}=\nu$$